# For all arithmetic sequences $a_1, a_2, a_3,...$ that has $(a_1)^2+(a_{11})^2\leq100$, what's the maximum value of $S=a_{11}+a_{12}+...+a_{21}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

For all arithmetic sequences $a_1, a_2, a_3,...$ that has $(a_1)^2+(a_{11})^2\leq100$, what's the maximum value of $S=a_{11}+a_{12}+...+a_{21}$?

I was given this question for homework for a class I'm taking, and I don't know how  to start on it. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the difference of the sequence is $d,$ then you know that $a_1^2 + (a_1+ 10d )^2 \leq 100,$ and you want to find the maximum of $11a_1 + 165 d$ (check the arithmetic). Lagrange multipliers are your friend here.

**EDIT** To avoid Lagrange multipliers:

1. write $a_1^2 + (a_1+10d)^2$ as an ellipse in standard form (completing various squares).
2. Change variables to make the ellipse a disk
3. Find the intersection of the line (in new coordinates) with the disk. There will be two points, one of which will have the bigger value.

Comment: How do I use $a_1^2+(a_1+10d)^2≤100$ to find the maximum, though? I haven't learned Lagrange multipliers yet.

Answer (score 1):

One way to start:

$$
 S = a_{11}+a_{12}+\cdots+a_{21} = \frac{11}2(a_{11} + a_{21}),
$$
$$
a_{21} = a_1 + 20\left(\frac{a_{11}-a_1}{10}\right)
= 2 a_{11} -  a_1.
$$
$$
S = \frac{11}2(3a_{11} - a_1).
$$

So you just need to maximize $\frac{11}2(3a_{11} - a_1)$
with the constraint $a_1^2 + a_{11}^2 \leq 100.$
That's the same as maximizing $\frac2{11}S = 3a_{11} - a_1$
under the same conditions.

It may also help if  you determine that when $S$ is maximized,
$a_{11} > 0$ and $a_1^2 + a_{11}^2 = 100.$